# Kendo MVC chart is displaying different dates than what we send in the JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

We are having an issue where, in one of our Kendo charts we are developing to display some weekly data. The JSON that we're sending to the view looks like:

```
[
    {"WeekofYear":45,"Value":96.08,"WeekBeginDate":"\/Date(1415422800000)\/"},
    {"WeekofYear":46,"Value":97.40,"WeekBeginDate":"\/Date(1416027600000)\/"},
    {"WeekofYear":47,"Value":96.50,"WeekBeginDate":"\/Date(1416632400000)\/"},
    {"WeekofYear":48,"Value":93.93,"WeekBeginDate":"\/Date(1417237200000)\/"},
    {"WeekofYear":49,"Value":96.76,"WeekBeginDate":"\/Date(1417842000000)\/"},
    {"WeekofYear":50,"Value":94.50,"WeekBeginDate":"\/Date(1418446800000)\/"}
]
```

The dates in the JSON represent the date on each Saturday of the week in question. However, when we render the graph, it displays the date from the Sunday of the week instead, as displayed in the screenshot.

[Chart Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VecoU.png)

We are using the following code in the Razor engine to generate the chart:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<Dashboard.Models.CentralScheduling>()
.Name("CallsAnswered")
.Title("% of Calls Answered")
.Legend(legend => legend.Visible(false))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Read(read => read.Action("CentralScheduling", "Dashboard").Data("filterStatusData")))
    .Series(series =>
    {
        series.Line(d => d.Value)
    .Tooltip(t => t.Visible(true).Template("#=value#%"));
    })
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Categories(model => model.WeekBeginDate)   //WeekBeginDate holds the date at the end of the week for this particular chart    
        .Labels(labels => labels.Format("MM/dd/yyyy")
        .Rotation(-60)
        )
    )
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis
    .Numeric().Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0}%"))
    .Max(100)
    )
    .SeriesColors("#3aafff","#ffb800","#a7008f","#99c900","#FF0000", "#002060")
)
```

The filterStatusData function sets a flag that we use in the controller to generate the JSON for the calling chart.

I am at a loss to explain why a different date is being chosen for the chart rather than the one that we are supplying.

Comment: I'm getting Friday 23:00 for those dates , probably because of local times zones - I'm sure kendo has a setting for which time-zone to use

Comment: Yeah, we're in EST here so the times are coming out to 00:00:00 for us, and that's what our original date dimension table the data is pulled from is based on as well.

Comment: I provided an answer , is that an option for you?  I mean JSON is really just sending a string anyways , and Kendo is really just taking that string and turning it into a javascript Date object.  So I see no problem with what I suggested

Comment: We're going to try that today and see what happens. The other developer working on this project was already gone when we saw the posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option - this is comming from Telerik - is to pass the date  as a string from the server instead of a .Net DateTime object.  The client will parse it just like it does a date object.  Use this format "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM"

so your json would be something like:

```
[
    {"WeekofYear":45,"Value":96.08,"WeekBeginDate":"2014-12-16 07:00"},
    ...
```

Comment: That works! We'll need to format the label a bit different, since the .Format("MM/dd/yyyy") in the View doesn't seem to want to work with a string field, but it's giving us the correct date now.